# code for user visibility in android activity

Tags: android, android-activity

```
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {

            new FacultySyncerBg().execute("");
        }
    }
```

This I have for fragment how can i use that in activity. If I copied the same code in activity I am getting error at this point please send me the solution.

Comment: please show the error

Comment: Run time exception or compile time?

Comment: When I use the code in fragment it works fine but not in android activity class.

Comment: Compile time error

Comment: You cannot use this in Activity. This Method is only for Fragment

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call method of Fragment from Activity, that method is accessible for Fragments only.

According to docs -

> setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) - Set a hint to the system
>   about whether this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The setUserVisibleHint(boolean) is can used only in Fragment not in Activity
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)

Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user. This hint defaults to true and is persistent across fragment instance state save and restore.

An app may set this to false to indicate that the fragment's UI is scrolled out of visibility or is otherwise not directly visible to the user. This may be used by the system to prioritize operations such as fragment lifecycle updates or loader ordering behavior.

Comment: How can i call asynch task automatically when activity is started.

Comment: You can put in onCreate Method of Activity

Comment: If your requirement is like to call a Asynctask at once only then you can manage from Application class Contructor and Application class onCreate() which is called only at once
@Dee Let me know the exact requirement

Comment: I have array of objects that i will directly get from web service so I have added asynch task when I click the button it should get all the objects from web service and display to the user.

Comment: @Dee You need this API call at once only or multiple times?

Comment: Student gives rating for the faculty members so once for a student.

Comment: So you have to manage using one flag variable which is return true and false

Answer (score 0):

```
Do like this

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Fragments());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if (position == 0)
                {
                    DemoFragment1 fragment1 = (DemoFragment1) fragments.get(0);
                    fragment1.setUserVisibleHint(true);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayList<Fragment> Fragments()
    {
        fragments.clear();

        fragments.add(new DemoFragment1());
        fragments.add(new DemoFragment2());
        fragments.add(new DemoFragment3());

      return fragments;
    }

}
```